# How to create a new custom action/view in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a number of models/resources in my ActiveAdmin applications. I already have a page associated to my "Plan" model/resource with index, show, create, and edit actions. I would like to have another page/view, like /admin/plans/report, in which I can have scopes and filters, and then based on the selected Plans, I would like to select another resources, and then finally iterating on a set of resources and represent them in a hierarchical view.

These are the important aspects for me:

- Being able to use custom scopes and filters
- Being able to select another resources and iterate on them manually

If collection_action can help, can anyone explain me how exactly I can define it, select my resources and manually display them? How's the flow like?